# how to access live stream of ip camera in android app

Tags: android, live-streaming, ip-camera

i want to access live stream from ip camera in android app. i am using **D-Link DCS-5020L** camera. i searched a lot over internet for solution could not figure out anything.
i want to know which protocol to set **rtsp,http** or any other. and how to create **url** for stream.
i am using videoview in android app to show video. i also tried to play some public ip camera feeds but it gives the same error

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://64.122.208.241:8000/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://64.122.208.241:8000/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240
```

Comment: use rstp, before you implement try playing feed using VLC. for the player within the app, I used SurfaceView and played using MediaPlayer but was not able to add buttons

Answer (score 1):

I've done a project some time ago. There I used a custom view instead of the default videoView. Here are the classes, try it.

MjpegView.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "MjpegView";

    public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
    public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
    public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
    public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

    public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1;
    public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
    public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

    private MjpegViewThread thread;
    private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;
    private boolean showFps = false;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    private boolean surfaceDone = false;
    private Paint overlayPaint;
    private int overlayTextColor;
    private int overlayBackgroundColor;
    private int ovlPos;
    private int dispWidth;
    private int dispHeight;
    private int displayMode;

    public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private int frameCounter = 0;
        private long start;
        private Bitmap ovl;

        public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) {
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        }

        private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
            int tempx;
            int tempy;
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
                float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
                bmw = dispWidth;
                bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
                if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                    bmh = dispHeight;
                    bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
                }
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN){
                return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
            synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
                dispWidth = width;
                dispHeight = height;
            }
        }

        private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
            Rect b = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
            int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
            int bheight = b.height()+2;
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
            c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
            p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
            c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
            return bm;
        }

        public void run() {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
            Bitmap bm;
            int width;
            int height;
            Rect destRect;
            Canvas c = null;
            Paint p = new Paint();
            String fps;
            while (mRun) {
                if(surfaceDone) {
                    try {
                        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                            try {
                                bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                                destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                                if(showFps) {
                                    p.setXfermode(mode);
                                    if(ovl != null) {
                                        height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                        width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                        c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                    }
                                    p.setXfermode(null);
                                    frameCounter++;
                                    if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                        fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+" fps";
                                        frameCounter = 0;
                                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                        ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.getStackTrace();
                                Log.d(TAG, "catch IOException hit in run", e);
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
        setFocusable(true);
        overlayPaint = new Paint();
        overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
        overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
        overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
        displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
        dispWidth = getWidth();
        dispHeight = getHeight();
    }

    public void startPlayback() {
        if(mIn != null) {
            mRun = true;
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopPlayback() {
        mRun = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "catch IOException hit in stopPlayback", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs); init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) {
        thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceDone = false;
        stopPlayback();
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceDone = true;
    }

    public void showFps(boolean b) {
        showFps = b;
    }

    public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) {
        mIn = source;
        startPlayback();
    }

    public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) {
        overlayPaint = p;
    }

    public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) {
        overlayTextColor = c;
    }

    public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) {
        overlayBackgroundColor = c;
    }

    public void setOverlayPosition(int p) {
        ovlPos = p;
    }

    public void setDisplayMode(int s) {
        displayMode = s;
    }
}
```

VideoViewFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import aronz.lab.streamvideo.MjpegInputStream;
import aronz.lab.streamvideo.MjpegView;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class VideoViewFragment extends Fragment {

    // Declare variables
//        VideoView videoview;
//    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    private static final String TAG = "MjpegActivity";

    private MjpegView mv;
    // Physical display width and height.
    private static int displayWidth = 0;
    private static int displayHeight = 0;

    // Video URL
//    public String path = main.Path;
//    String VideoURL = path + "Video1.mp4";
//        String VideoURL = "http://192.168.43.1:8080";

    //sample public cam
        String URL = "http://192.168.43.72:8080/video";
//    String URL = "http://192.168.43.134:5432/XMLParser/Video1.mp4";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_view, container, false);
//        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_view,
//                container, false);
//        return view;

        mv = (MjpegView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        new DoRead().execute(URL);
        return viewGroup;
//        mv = new MjpegView(this.getContext());
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mv.stopPlayback();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public class DoRead extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MjpegInputStream> {
        protected MjpegInputStream doInBackground(String... Url) {
            //TODO: if camera has authentication deal with it and don't just not work

//            HttpResponse res = null;
//            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.d(TAG, "1. Sending http request");
            try {
                java.net.URL url = new URL(Url[0]); // here is your URL path
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

//                res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url[0])));
//                Log.d(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = " + res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                Log.d(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = " + responseCode);
                if(responseCode==401){
                    //You must turn off camera User Access Control before this will work
                    return null;
                }
                return new MjpegInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-ClientProtocolException", e);
                //Error connecting to camera
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(MjpegInputStream result) {
            if(result != null) {
                mv.setSource(result);
                mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
                mv.showFps(true);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

MjpegInputStream.java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
    private static final String TAG = "MjpegInputStream";

private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
private int mContentLength = -1;

public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) {
    super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH));
}

private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
        if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
            seqIndex++;
            if(seqIndex == sequence.length) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        } else {
            seqIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
    return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
}

private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(headerIn);
    return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
}

public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
    mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
    reset();
    byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
    readFully(header);
    try {
        mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.getStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "catch NumberFormatException hit", nfe);
        mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER);
    }
    reset();
    byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
    skipBytes(headerLen);
    readFully(frameData);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
}
}
```

Comment: what is **MjpegInputStream**  ? @Nizam

Comment: Added the missing class.

Comment: When I try this, it runs with no error but I get a black picture in `MjpegView`. Is there any working sample which I could actually check if I'm missing something?